# Consume webservice in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have access to webservice https://uslugaterytws1test.stat.gov.pl/terytws1.svc with wsdl https://uslugaterytws1test.stat.gov.pl/wsdl/terytws1.wsdl

Username: TestPubliczny and password: 1234abcd

I try import wsdl and then place 2 components :

```
  object htpr1: THTTPRIO
    WSDLLocation = 'https://uslugaterytws1test.stat.gov.pl/wsdl/terytws1.wsdl'
    Service = 'TerytWs1'
    Port = 'custom'
    HTTPWebNode = htprqrsp1
    Converter.Options = [soSendMultiRefObj, soTryAllSchema, soRootRefNodesToBody, soCacheMimeResponse, soUTF8EncodeXML]
    Left = 264
    Top = 325
  end
  object htprqrsp1: THTTPReqResp
    UserName = 'TestPubliczny'
    Password = '1234abcd'
    UseUTF8InHeader = True
    InvokeOptions = [soIgnoreInvalidCerts, soAutoCheckAccessPointViaUDDI]
    WebNodeOptions = []
    UDDIOperator = '0'
    Left = 296
    Top = 376
  end
```

And in .pas file :

```
var
  ten: terytws1.ITerytWs1;

begin
ten := (htpr1 as terytws1.ITerytWs1);

ShowMessage(BoolToStr(ten.CzyZalogowany));
end;
```

But I get request timeout,where at the same time consuming using app in C# working ok.

In C#  provider of webservice sugest to use this code :

```
try
         {
           var proxy = new ChannelFactory<ServiceReferenceWCF.ITerytWs1>("custom");

proxy.Credentials.UserName.UserName = TestPubliczny; 

proxy.Credentials.UserName.Password = 1234abcd; 

var result = proxy.CreateChannel(); 

var test = result.CzyZalogowany();                 
         }
         catch (Exception ex) { }
```

and

```
<client>
   <endpoint address="https://uslugaterytws1test.stat.gov.pl/terytws1.svc"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="custom"
contract="ServiceReference1.ITerytWs1" name="custom" />
</client> 

<bindings>
     <customBinding>
       <binding name="custom">
           <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default"  

authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" 
       requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true"
messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruar
y2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
             <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
             <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
           </security>
           <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
           <httpsTransport  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  

maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"/> 
                </binding>
     </customBinding>
  </bindings>
```

and as I write before from C# I consume service without problems

Comment: Do you set username / password also in the Delphi code (it is not shown)?

Comment: If the C# request is successful, you could use Wireshark or Fiddler2 to capture the request and ompare it with the Delphi request

Comment: Username and password is set only in dfm as in  first post

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Delphi XE5 update 2